# Problems setting the content description to image button

Tags: android, android-widget, android-view

Hello i am trying to set a content description to my button buy when i try to access to it the value that return to me is null.

Here is the code of the button.

```
//This is the button of the payment.
ImageButton make_pay = new ImageButton(this);
make_pay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_product);
makePay.addView(make_pay);
makePay.setContentDescription("Precio");
```

This is the code that i use to access:

```
make_pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                                        

        @Override
        public void onClick(View makepay) {
            LinearLayout wrap_area = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.division2);
            TextView test = new TextView(FrontActivity.this);
            wrap_area.addView(test);
            if (makepay.getContentDescription() == null){
                    test.setText("Precio:1");
            }else{
                    test.setText(makepay.getContentDescription().toString());
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the content description to makePay object (whatever it is, probabbly a ViewGroup). But then, you are setting the listener to the make_pay ImageButton, which is the one received by the listener arguments. Thus, it's content description is not the one assigned to the other object.

Try changing this:

```
makePay.setContentDescription("Precio");
```

with this:

```
make_pay.setContentDescription("Precio");
```

Anyway, try not to name your objects in such a similar way. It could lead to big confussions.